# How to redirect textbox value to a URL?

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to add a search box in the navbar of my website. When a user enters a query, I would like the action to be redirecting the user to the page: /search_results?query=text

I have the following code in my template, however it does not work:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('search_results')}}">
                    <div class="md-form my-0">
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text"
                               placeholder="Search for something!" aria-label="Search"
                               name="query">
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-white btn-md my-2 my-sm-0 ml-3" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
```

Can you let me know how my form should look so that when submit is clicked, users are redirected to the page?

I am using Python and Flask - is that something that should be done in that logic?

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like page you want to direct to accepts GET requests if you can see the parameters it accepts in the URL itself.  So, you may just need to switch the method from POST to GET.  Google does the same i.e.:  https://www.google.com/search?q=test

Comment: Have you tried using your web browser and inspecting how search requests are handled?  Typically by pressing F12 and going to the network tab you can inspect how the form is passed from the client's end.